# java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4060cc48

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, thumbnails, runtimeexception

Below there is the code to create Thumbnail images more than 4000 from MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail in doInBackground() AsynchTask. Now I am executing in Android 2.3.6. Its not creating Thumbnails in between I'm getting *RuntimeException*.

```
private void loadImages() {

    try {
        columns = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE };
        orderBy = new String(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

        fileCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                null, null, orderBy);

        image_column_index = fileCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.imageCount = fileCursor.getCount();

        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.imageCount];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.imageCount];
        GlobalValues.IMAGE_ARR_PATH = new String[this.imageCount];
        GlobalValues.IMAGE_THUMBNAILSSELECTION = new boolean[this.imageCount];
        GlobalValues.IMAGES_SIZE = new String[this.imageCount];

        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.imageCount];
        if (GlobalValues.IMAGE_SELECTION != null) {
            thumbnailsselection = GlobalValues.IMAGE_SELECTION;
            GlobalValues.IMAGE_THUMBNAILSSELECTION = thumbnailsselection;
        }
        int inSample = 1;
        BitmapFactory.Options   opts=null;

        System.out.println("imageCount:"+imageCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.imageCount; i++) {
            fileCursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = fileCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = fileCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            arrPath[i] = fileCursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            GlobalValues.IMAGE_ARR_PATH[i] = fileCursor
                    .getString(dataColumnIndex);
            GlobalValues.IMAGES_SIZE[i] = fileCursor.getString(fileCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE));

        opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        opts.inSampleSize = inSample;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
                 bMap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        context.getContentResolver(), id,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, opts);
             if(bMap != null && !bMap.isRecycled())
                thumbnails[i]= bMap;    
            } else {
                if (arrPath[i].endsWith(".png")) {
                     bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrPath[i],opts);
                    bMap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
                            bMap, 96, 96);
                     if(bMap != null && !bMap.isRecycled() )
                    thumbnails[i]= bMap;    
                } else{
                    System.out.println("index:"+i);

                //Getting Error in below code

                     bMap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails
                            .getThumbnail(
                                    context.getContentResolver(),
                                    id,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                                    (BitmapFactory.Options) opts);
                     System.gc();
                        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                     thumbnails[i]= bMap;
                if (bMap != null && !bMap.isRecycled()) {

                    bMap.recycle();
                    bMap = null; 
                }


                }
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        fileCursor = null;
    }
}
```

I am getting below exception:

> 07-03 12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap
>   android.graphics.Bitmap@4060cc48 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1044) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:325)
>   07-03 12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:872) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1586) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.widget.GridView.dispatchDraw(GridView.java:1948) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2967) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1574) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1921)
>   07-03 12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1528) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1264) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 07-03 12:40:37.269:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   07-03 12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 07-03
>   12:40:37.269: E/AndroidRuntime(3185):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

You store a Bitmaps in array `thumbnails[i]= bMap;`. I suppose you use them later to draw?

And then you call `bMap.recycle();` which frees bitmap data stored in native memory. You should only call `recycle();` on a bitmaps you plan to not use anymore.